# Javascript return different results for different Array initialize

Tags: javascript

So I create two arrays with different syntaxes and `includes` method returns different results

```
new Array(['foo', 'bar']).includes('foo') ? false : true; // => true

['foo', 'bar'].includes('foo') ? false : true; // => false
```

Is there anything wrong? I'm tested on Chrome version 114/ MacOS

Found it, I used the wrong syntax, it should be

```
new Array('foo', 'bar').includes('foo') ? true : false; // => true

['foo', 'bar'].includes('foo') ? true : false; // => true
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is when creating an array with array constructor with a single argumrnt, it creates an array with that passed array as the single element.

```js
const arr = new Array(['aa', 'bb']);
console.log(arr); //[["aa","bb"]]
```

Comment: Got it, I used wrong syntax